# NSAlert not visible if open near screen edge in macOS Catalina

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsalert

For windows located near the screen edges:

On some monitors (or computers) NSAlert opened as a sheet on a window moves the window to make the alert sheet visible. But on some others monitors (or computers) windows near the screen edge are not moved and the sheet window is partially hidden beyond the screen edge.

Below are two screenshots of the SAME program launched on MacBook(1) and mac mini (2). The main window of the program is very near to the screen edge:

[see: on MacBook the alert moves the window and its fully visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3iew.jpg)

[see: on my mac mini with 4K display, the window is not moved and the alert is partially hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxL9w.jpg)

This is how it looks on MacBook: https://youtu.be/CJQSvLWKyfM
And the same program on Mac mini: https://youtu.be/Pfu6ODxubM0

Both computers have exactly same macOS (build level).
Any settings to make the alert always fully visible?

Comment: The window can be moved differently depending on whether the Dock is always visible or auto-hides (it will move so that the sheet is out from under a currently visible Dock) - does it do the same thing on the left edge of the screen?

Comment: Is Reduce motion in the System Prefs switched on?

Comment: Thank you @Willeke . That was it!!! When turn off the "reduce motion", the window started to move when the alert is displayed.